# Magento2: Use Blank-Theme-Icons/Blank-Theme-Icons.woff2 in my custom theme

Tags: magento2, custom-theme, icons-blank-theme

**In PageSpeed Insights:**
Ensure text remains visible during Webfont load
Leverage the font-display CSS feature to ensure text is user-visible while web fonts are loading.

Blank-Theme-Icons/Blank-Theme-Icons.woff2
I want to use this font in my custom theme and adding

```
font-display :swap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the Blank-Theme-Icons.woff2 font in your CSS file by adding below lines in your theme's CSS file.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icons-blank-theme';
  src: url('../fonts/Blank-Theme-Icons/Blank-Theme-Icons.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/Blank-Theme-Icons/Blank-Theme-Icons.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: Thank's @sumit. It's working

Comment: Leverage the font-display CSS  for en_US/fonts/Luma-Icons.woff2 , how can we fix this ?

Comment: @Pravin, you got solution?

Comment: @Sumit, can we use this in our custom css file ? 
as we already have this file still while deploying we are facing No matching definition was found for `@family-name:'icons-blank-theme'

Answer (score 1):

Create new file _icons.less (app/design/frontend///web/css/source/_icons.less)

And paste this code

```
// /**
//  * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
//  * See COPYING.txt for license details.
//  */

& when (@media-common = true) {
    .lib-font-face(
        @family-name: @icons__font-name,
        @font-path: @icons__font-path,
        @font-weight: normal,
        @font-style: normal,
        @font-display: swap
    );
}
```